# How to test an AngularJS factory method that returns a $timeout promise with a $http.get inside?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

For specific purposes, I had to write a factory method that returns a `$timeout` promise that, inside of it, returns a `$http.get` promise.

I want to test if a call to my factory method will call the `$http.get` with the correct mocked URL (`mocked-get-path`).

Here is my factory code:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('MyApp', []);

  angular.module('MyApp')
    .constant("ROUTES", {
      get: "real-get-path"
    });

  angular.module('MyApp')
    .factory('MyFactory', ['$http', '$timeout', 'ROUTES', MyFactory]);

  function MyFactory($http, $timeout, ROUTES) {
    return {
      myGet: function(id) {
        var random = Math.random() * 1000;
        return $timeout(function () {
            return $http.get(ROUTES.get, {
              params: { id: id }
            })
              .then(function() {
                return response.data;
              });
        }, random);
      }
    };
  }
})();
```

And my test specification:

```
describe('simple factory test', function() {
  var $http, $timeout, scope, MyFactory;

  var ROUTES = {
      get: 'mocked-get-path'
  };

  beforeEach(module('MyApp', function ($provide) {
      $provide.constant('ROUTES', ROUTES);
  }));

  beforeEach(module('MyApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$http_, _$timeout_, _MyFactory_) {
    scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    $http = _$http_;
    $timeout = _$timeout_;
    MyFactory = _MyFactory_;
  }));

  it('should use ROUTES.get on method myGet', function(done) {
    spyOn(Math, "random").and.returnValue(0.01);

    MyFactory.myGet('elem1')
      .then(function(res) {
        expect($http.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(ROUTES.get);
        done();
      });
    $timeout.flush();
  });
});
```

You can see that I tried to write a `expect` for the `$http.get` inside the `then`, but it didn't work.

I receive this error from Jasmine:

> Error: Unexpected request: GET mocked-get-path?id=elem1

I made a Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/Ia6Q6GvKZOkNU2B8GrO1

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When testing `$http` you are going to want to use `$httpBackend.when`

In your case:

```
it('should use ROUTES.get on method myGet', function(done) {
  spyOn(Math, "random").and.returnValue(0.01);
  spyOn($http, "get").and.callThrough();

  MyFactory.myGet('elem1')
    .then(function(res) {
      expect($http.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(ROUTES.get, {params: {id: 'elem1'}});
      done();
    });

  $httpBackend
    .when('GET', "mocked-get-path?id=elem1")
    .respond(200, { foo: 'bar' });

  $timeout.flush(100);

  $timeout.verifyNoPendingTasks();
  $httpBackend.flush();

});
```

This will cause `$httpBackend` to complete your request successfully allowing your `.then` with the expect to execute.

[Plunkr showing solution](https://plnkr.co/edit/RhLCKMrzXFY5wxikc4RQ)

[ngmock fundamentals](http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/06/26/unit-testing-http-ngmock-fundamentals/)

I hope this helps! Have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I've tried something like this and didn't work. Please check this modification I wrote with your suggestion: https://plnkr.co/edit/RwD3y9OmxSEywUhq2mUh

Comment: I've solved it.  My solution was missing $httpBackend.flush() after $timeout.flush()

Comment: Thank you so much! Here is the modification: https://plnkr.co/edit/YvF3Lem8pYRmm0SpCke2

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to add expected calls to the httpBackend like this:

```
var  $httpBackend;
beforeEach(function () {
        inject(function ( _$httpBackend_ ) {
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        }
```

....

```
it('....', function(){
    //before the rest of the test
    $httpBackend.expectGET('url').respond("OK");

});
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend

So, your code will look like this:

```
describe('simple directive', function() {
  var $http, $timeout, scope, MyFactory, $httpBackend;

  var ROUTES = {
      get: 'mocked-get-path'
  };

  beforeEach(module('MyApp', function ($provide) {
      $provide.constant('ROUTES', ROUTES);
  }));

  beforeEach(module('MyApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$http_, _$timeout_, _MyFactory_, _$httpBackend_) {
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    $http = _$http_;
    $timeout = _$timeout_;
    MyFactory = _MyFactory_;
  }));

  it('should use ROUTES.get on method myGet', function(done) {
    spyOn(Math, "random").and.returnValue(0.01);
    $httpBackend.expectGET("mocked-get-path?id=elem1").respond("OK");
    MyFactory.myGet('elem1')
      .then(function(res) {
        expect($http.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(ROUTES.get);
        done();
      });
    $timeout.flush();
  });
});
```

It will get you passed the unexpected GET error. But then there is another issue about not getting the call within the timeout period.

And, providing that now you are expecting a correct call at the $httpBackend, you can simplify your test case by removing the async nature of it like this:

(remove the paremeter done, and simplify the test code)

```
it('should use ROUTES.get on method myGet', function() {
    spyOn(Math, "random").and.returnValue(0.01);
    $httpBackend.expectGET("mocked-get-path?id=elem1").respond("OK");
    MyFactory.myGet('elem1');
    $timeout.flush();
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried what you suggested but it didn't work. Please check this modification I wrote with your suggestion: https://plnkr.co/edit/b0hyazxaC5P3qKpLjqLm

Comment: I've attached the complete code that fixes the unexpected GET problem.

Comment: Thanks again. Now the error is other: "Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL." Here is the modification: https://plnkr.co/edit/RwD3y9OmxSEywUhq2mUh

Comment: see my last edit. your test conditions are now checked by expectations on httpBackend, so it can be done by sync calls.

Comment: Thanks again, but why the Jasmine result tells "SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS should use ROUTES.get on method myGet"? Updated plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/RwD3y9OmxSEywUhq2mUh

Comment: Because, you don't have any expect() calls inside your test case. But your original test case was testing for something, that is covered by the httpBackend.expectGET. So, you may ignore the message, or add some other expectations.

Comment: Ok. I just added expect(MyFactory.myGet).toBeDefined(); to supress the message. Thanks a lot!